# WPF volume dial code tutorial code has issues in my code but none in the tutorial code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, wpf-controls

Hey all I need some help with getting the code below working. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-EqckhJNvI) and most things work but there are a few things in the code that seem not to work for some reason. All this code looks like the code in the tutorial so I'm unsure of what's going on?

User control xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="carProg.dial"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:carProgForKids"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="450" Width="450">
    <Grid Manipulation.ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Margin="30" Fill="#FFFFE15D"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FFFFFDF3" 
                     Height="100" Stroke="Black" Margin="0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace carProg
{
    public partial class dial : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public dial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Angle = GetAngle(e.Position, this.RenderSize);
            this.Amount = (int)(this.Angle / 360 * 100);
        }

        int m_Amount = default(int);
        public int Amount { 
            get { return m_Amount; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref m_Amount, value); 
        } }

        double m_Angle = default(double);
        public double Angle { 
            get { return m_Angle; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref m_Angle, value); 
        } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]);

        public enum Quadrants : int { nw = 2, ne = 1, sw = 4, se = 3 }
        private double GetAngle(Point touchPoint, Size circleSize)
        {
            var _X = touchPoint.X - (circleSize.Width / 2d);
            var _Y = circleSize.Height - touchPoint.Y - (circleSize.Height / 2d);
            var _Hypot = Math.Sqrt(_X * _X + _Y * _Y);
            var _Value = Math.Asin(_Y / _Hypot) * 180 / Math.PI;
            var _Quadrant = (_X >= 0) ?
                (_Y >= 0) ? Quadrants.ne : Quadrants.se :
                (_Y >= 0) ? Quadrants.nw : Quadrants.sw;
            switch (_Quadrant)
            {
                case Quadrants.ne: _Value = 090 - _Value; break;
                case Quadrants.nw: _Value = 270 + _Value; break;
                case Quadrants.se: _Value = 090 - _Value; break;
                case Quadrants.sw: _Value = 270 + _Value; break;
            }
            return _Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the issues are:

e.Position
Error:

> Error CS1061 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' does not contain a
> definition for 'Position' and no accessible extension method
> 'Position' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

SetProperty
Error:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required formal parameter '' of 'dial.SetProperty(ref T, T, ?)'

CallerMemberName
Error:

> Error CS1061 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' does not contain a
> definition for 'Position' and no accessible extension method
> 'Position' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

And on the xaml user control:

<Grid Manipulation.ManipulationMode="All"
Error:

> Error Manipulation is not active on the specified element.

Not sure why I am getting these errors since it's the same code the video tutorial is going off of and it has no errors showing like mine does..

**UPDATE #1**
[image]

**UPDATE #2**
The code should produce a dial:

[image]

**UPDATE #3: Let mouse act as touch device**

Adding the MouseTouchDevice.cs class in [BlakeNUI](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=blakenui):

```
public class MouseTouchDevice : TouchDevice, ITouchDevice
{
//Class Members

private static MouseTouchDevice device;

public Point Position { get; set; }

//Public Static Methods

public static void RegisterEvents(FrameworkElement root)
{
    root.PreviewMouseDown += MouseDown;
    root.PreviewMouseMove += MouseMove;
    root.PreviewMouseUp += MouseUp;
    root.LostMouseCapture += LostMouseCapture;
    root.MouseLeave += MouseLeave;
}

//Private Static Methods

private static void MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (device != null &&
        device.IsActive)
    {
        device.ReportUp();
        device.Deactivate();
        device = null;
    }
    device = new MouseTouchDevice(e.MouseDevice.GetHashCode());
    device.SetActiveSource(e.MouseDevice.ActiveSource);
    device.Position = e.GetPosition(null);
    device.Activate();
    device.ReportDown();
}

private static void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (device != null &&
        device.IsActive)
    {
        device.Position = e.GetPosition(null);
        device.ReportMove();
    }
}

private static void MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    LostMouseCapture(sender, e);
}

static void LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (device != null &&
        device.IsActive)
    {
        device.Position = e.GetPosition(null);
        device.ReportUp();
        device.Deactivate();
        device = null;
    }
}

static void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    LostMouseCapture(sender, e);
}

//Constructors

public MouseTouchDevice(int deviceId) :
    base(deviceId)
{
    Position = new Point();
}

//Overridden methods

public override TouchPointCollection GetIntermediateTouchPoints(IInputElement relativeTo)
{
    return new TouchPointCollection();
}

public override TouchPoint GetTouchPoint(IInputElement relativeTo)
{
    Point point = Position;
}
```

to my project and placing this:

```
public watchingMovie(String movie)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MouseTouchDevice.RegisterEvents(this);
    ...
}
```

Allows it to function as if you were working with it on a touch device.

Comment: Please [see](https://dotnetfiddle.net/16xFZi) this, I know it doesn't compile there, it's just a placeholder for code. I am able to compile with a few changes. You do know that `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs` is for touches correct; I can't test that, but I was able to change the angle and the white circle did move... Test my changes and let me know if they work out.

Comment: The tutorial you included a link to is written in UWP not WPF.

Comment: @zaggler I did those modifications and it looks like the code behind no longer have errors. However, the xaml seems to have them now and I'm not able to compile and test due to that.

user9938 - Hum I did not know this. Surly this can be adapted to WPF easy?

Comment: @zaggler **Error Manipulation is not active on the specified element.**

Comment: @zaggler see my updated OP

Comment: @zaggler The first <Grid>. Says line 8.

Comment: @zaggler That is what it has - **<Grid IsManipulationEnabled="True" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta">**

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: You are using the WPF template and not the UWP as mentioned by user9938, right?

Comment: Go ahead and zip your project up then and post it and ill try loading that then. Also go ahead and add this to your answer so this comment section doesn't go on forever.

Comment: @zaggler please post the code you have here (https://dotnetfiddle.net/16xFZi) as the answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @StealthRT I've removed comments that weren't necessary anymore as I've added the answer; you may want to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the issues are:

> Error CS1061 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Position' and no accessible extension method 'Position' accepting a first argument of type 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This error is because it doesn't exist, you can replace `.Position` with [ManipulationOrigin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.manipulationdeltaeventargs.manipulationorigin?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Input_ManipulationDeltaEventArgs_ManipulationOrigin) which gets the point from which the manipulation originated and returns a `System.Windows.Point`:

```
 this.Angle = GetAngle(e.ManipulationOrigin, this.RenderSize);
```

> Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '' of 'dial.SetProperty(ref T, T, ?)'

Please see example implementation below:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
 {
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
    storage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    return true;
 }
```

> Error Manipulation is not active on the specified element.

To fix this issue set [IsManipulationEnabled="True"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ismanipulationenabled?view=net-5.0) on the grid iteself which means manipulation is enabled for the UIElement

All of this wrapped up:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace carProg
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for dial.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class dial : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public dial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Angle = GetAngle(e.ManipulationOrigin, this.RenderSize);
            this.Amount = (int)(this.Angle / 360 * 100);
        }

        int m_Amount = default(int);
        public int Amount
        {
            get { return m_Amount; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref m_Amount, value);
            }
        }

        double m_Angle = default(double);
        public double Angle
        {
            get { return m_Angle; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref m_Angle, value);
            }
        }

        // Please note the changes with OnPropertyChanged and SetProperty
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propName);
            return true;
        }

        public enum Quadrants : int { nw = 2, ne = 1, sw = 4, se = 3 }
        private double GetAngle(Point touchPoint, Size circleSize)
        {
            var _X = touchPoint.X - (circleSize.Width / 2d);
            var _Y = circleSize.Height - touchPoint.Y - (circleSize.Height / 2d);
            var _Hypot = Math.Sqrt(_X * _X + _Y * _Y);
            var _Value = Math.Asin(_Y / _Hypot) * 180 / Math.PI;
            var _Quadrant = (_X >= 0) ?
                (_Y >= 0) ? Quadrants.ne : Quadrants.se :
                (_Y >= 0) ? Quadrants.nw : Quadrants.sw;
            switch (_Quadrant)
            {
                case Quadrants.ne: _Value = 090 - _Value; break;
                case Quadrants.nw: _Value = 270 + _Value; break;
                case Quadrants.se: _Value = 090 - _Value; break;
                case Quadrants.sw: _Value = 270 + _Value; break;
            }
            return _Value;
        }
    }
}

// Please note: IsManipulationEnabled on the grid
<Grid IsManipulationEnabled="True" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta">
        <Ellipse Margin="30"
                 Fill="#FFFFE15D"
                 Stroke="Black"
                 />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" CenterX="225" CenterY="225" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse Width="100"
                     Height="100"
                     Margin="0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Fill="#FFFFFDF3"
                     Stroke="Black"
                     />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I'd like to add, as what zaggle said, this wont work since its touch only so I updated my OP to reflect this change in order to use a mouse as the touch.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `e.Position` with `e.ManipulationOrigin` in the event handler and set the `IsManipulationEnabled` property of the `Grid` to `true` in the XAML markup:

```
<Grid  IsManipulationEnabled="True" ...
```

You also need to actually implement the `SetProperty<T>` method.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean to do a -1 on this! sorry!

Comment: Yep did but not sure who has downvoted my OP to -2?

Comment: @StealthRT it happens a lot to be honest, I gave it an upvote as it's a clear question with reproducible issues.